# TCPDF Paging with QR Code

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have to generate a PDF document that could take more than one page. Each page has a html table (that has a variable length), and a QR code at the bottom of the page. 
The QR code will be at the bottom of every page of the document, but, if that is too difficult to achieve, I can have it only in first page.
I have the problem that the text of the html table is printing over the QR code. I tried using `$pdf->setPageRegions` without any positive result, because the coordinates used to define the position of `QRCode` and for `setRegions` are in different units.
How can I achieve this?